# Save CAGradientLayer to NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedarchiver, cagradientlayer

I have a gradient in my app which I want to save to `NSUserDefaults`. My question is: Is it possible to save the gradient object itself using `NSKeyedArchiever`, or should I save the two gradient colors only, and then recreate the gradient with the saved colors on app launch?

Thanks!

Comment: Do the latter, save the colors

Comment: Can you provide a reason for your choice?

Comment: Classes like `CALayer` are dynamic objects. They could be recreated easily.

Comment: Yes, but why should I re-create it? Is it better for memory?

Comment: You was mentioning *recreate*. Actually it's waste of memory space to save entire classes like `CALayer`.

Comment: But UIColor is a class as well.

Comment: Yes, but it's not as complex as the layer class. You could also save only the R, G, B, alpha values. Anyway Apple discourages developers from saving complex classes like `CALayer` in user defaults.